# Change a style then with second click reset to original class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button and it takes some styles with first click.  But I want the user to be able to reset to the original with second click on own button or any button in page.

How can I do this?

---

my codes

```js
$("#checkButton").click(function() {
  $("#checkButton").css("color", "yellow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="checkButton">name 1</button>
```

---

Comment: I'd suggest using two or one CSS class for this, so you can check the condition and then decide what to set. `if($('#checkButton').hasClass("yo")) {....})`

Comment: The above duplicate answers your question.  However, I would also suggest sticking with classes and not using `.css`, then you can `addClass` `removClass` or `toggleClass`

Comment: Some answers were posted, but without knowing more about the context, I don't think they are useful. What is the bigger picture here?

Comment: Add class and use this code:  $(document).ready(function(){
                $(window).click(function(e) {
                    let clickedLement = e.target.id;
                    if (clickedLement == "checkButton" && !($("#checkButton").hasClass("color-class"))) {
                        $("#checkButton").addClass("color-class");
                    } else if ($("#checkButton").hasClass("color-class")) {
                       $("#checkButton").removeClass("color-class");
                   }  
                });
            }); Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with CSS styling, but I've made a below snippet in case if you want to change color without make CSS.

Check current color, and then set the different one.

```js
$("#checkButton").click(function() {
  var color = $("#checkButton").css("color")
  var yellow = "rgb(255, 255, 0)"
  
  if (color !== yellow) {
    $("#checkButton").css("color", yellow);
  } else {
    $("#checkButton").css("color", "");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="checkButton">name 1</button>
```

Comment: thank you I wanted exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is better to use a *class* and toggle that *class* using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) in each button click.

> [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.

```js
$("#checkButton").click(function () {
  $("#checkButton").toggleClass("colorClass");
});
```

```css
.colorClass{
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="checkButton">
  name 1
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will work for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .my-class{
                background-color: red; 
                color: yellow; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="checkButton" class="">Click Me!</button>


        <script>
            $("button").click(function () {
                $("#checkButton").toggleClass("my-class");
            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```